# Lagrange multiplier with 2 constraints

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I can't find X, Y, and Z in the following equation.
it's dificult
$$ F=5x^2+3y^2-2z+2xy+1+{\alpha}(3x+z-5)+{\beta}(4y-3z)
$$\begin{cases}
F_x=10x+2y+3{\alpha}=0 \\ 
F_y=6y+2x+4{\beta}=0 \\ 
F_z=-2+{\alpha}-3{\beta}=0 \\
g_1=3x+z=5 \\ 
g_2=4y-3z=0  \\ 
\end{cases}

Comment: Lagrange is overkill here because one could express both constraints in terms of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $12F_z-4F_x+9F_y$ eliminates $\alpha,\beta$ and gives you
$$-22x+46y=24\ .$$
Together with the equations from $g_1$ and $g_2$ this is a system of three linear equations in three unknowns and I'm sure you can solve it even though the arithmetic is a bit messy.

Comment: thanks my friend